# Can I rent a car and drive it one way from Seatle, WA to Anchorage, AK?

Tags: automobiles, alaska

We would like to pick up a rental car at the Seatle, WA airport and two weeks later return it to the airport in Anchorage, AK. Don't understand why we can't find any agencies that will do this. Does anyone have any ideas? We have put off this trip for years because we can't seem to work it out.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with having to take the rental car out of the country (you'll have to go via Canada).  You may have more luck actually calling a few agencies rather than trying to book online.

Comment: What are you asking? How to hire a car for that? Why you can't? At the moment, your question seems more like a complaint about the difficulty of your situation, not an actual question.

Comment: @AleksG Just as a side note: There is a [ferry from Washington to Alaska](http://www.dot.state.ak.us/amhs/) that lets you neatly avoid having to enter Canada.

Comment: @AleksG I've taken a US rental car into Canada with no special procedures. The only difference was that it was not a one-way rental.

Comment: @phoog did you tell the rental company that you were planning to go to Canada?

Comment: @AlexG yes I did.  Or rather I asked if I could.  They said "yes."  I asked if I needed to do anything special because of this, and they said "no."

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer ... cost.  Repositioning costs (ie getting the car back to Seattle) are too high and the likelihood of someone wanting that model car at the right time for a one way back to Seattle is about nil.

Cruise America does offer some one way rental options for RVs and Alaska based RV companies have options to drive new RVs up (though usually in late spring and usually spoken for well in advance).